# Automapper: use default mapping for all other members

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I have a lot of classes to map from IDataReader like this:

```
class Dest
{
   public string Field1;
   public string Field2;
   public string Field3;
}

...

public DestProfile
{
   CreateMap<IDataReader, Dest>()
     .ForMember(d => d.Field1, opt => opt.MapFrom(/*Do some custom convertion here*/)
     .ForAllOtherMembers(/*Do default convention-based mapping for all other members/*)
}
```

So i'd like to perform custom convertion on selected fields and do default mapping without explicitly coding.

Question looks very common, but I didn't find how to achieve this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So the most straightforward way is to write like this:

```
.ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src[opt.DestinationMember.Name]))
```

But there are some caveats. For example

```
.IncludeBase<IDataReader, Base>()
.ForAllOtherMembers(opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src[opt.DestinationMember.Name]))
```

Here ForAllOtherMembers will override your base class definition.